# Pelican: markdown codeblock '>' turned into '&gt;'

Tags: markdown, pelican

I am using Pelican 4.0.1 (under Debian stretch). In my markdown document I have a short piece of shell code in a codeblock:

```
foo > bar.txt
```

Unexpectedly, Pelican turned the `>` into the html equivalent `&gt;` which is not ideal in a code block:

```
foo &gt; bar.txt
```

What am I missing, here?

Edit:

the above line is what I see in my browser. The actual html source code of the resulting page is `foo &amp;gt; bar.txt` – so, aparently, Pelican does the html encoding twice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found out that this indeed a bug in Pelican 4.01 or one of it's dependencies (probably python-markdown). See this issue on github: https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/2493

I also found a workaround that works for me: the bug seems to only affect simple indented codeblocks like this:

```
some text

     foo > bar.txt

more text
```

The problem does not occur when the triple backtick syntax is used:

````
 some text
 ```
      foo > bar.txt
 ```
 more text
````